# Carregar listview com dados

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, listview

Tenho um form que pesquisa todas as notas cadastradas no sistema pelo código do cliente que foi cadastrado. Ao encontrar, lista todas as notas no listview.
Eu consegui fazer com que ele buscasse o cliente, porém, ele não está listando as notas desse cliente.
Não sei onde está o erro!

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
using Entidades.Entidades;
using Entidades.Vendas;
using Negocio.NotasNG;
using Negocio.Vendas;
using projeto.Modulos;
using projeto.Notas;
using projeto.Pesquisas;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace projeto.Vendas
{
public partial class FrmAdmNotas : Form
{

    public List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota> lista = new List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota>();
    public int iRetorno = 0;
    public FrmAdmNotas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MascaraCampoNumero.AplicarEventos(txt_CodigoCliente);
        MascaraCampoNumero.AplicarEventos(txt_CodigoNota);
        PrepararLista();
    }

    private void Bt_PesquisarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var lista = new NotasNG().ListarEntidadeViewPesquisaCliente();
        //Verifica se a lista está vazia
        if (lista.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sem dados para serem exibidos!", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }
        //Passa a lista para o formulário de pesquisa de cliente;

        var frmPesquisaC = new FrmPesquisaCliente("Listagem de Clientes");
        frmPesquisaC.lista = lista;
        frmPesquisaC.ShowDialog();

        var iRetorno = frmPesquisaC.iRetorno;
        //iRetorno = 0
        if (iRetorno < 1)
            return;

        txt_CodigoCliente.Text = iRetorno.ToString();

        Txt_CodigoCliente_Validating(txt_CodigoCliente, new CancelEventArgs());
        bt_PesquisarCliente.Focus();

    }

    private void Txt_CodigoCliente_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Verifica se está vazio
        if (txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
            return;

        var oCliente = new NotasNG().BuscarCliente(Convert.ToInt32(txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim()));
        var oNota = new NotasNG().BuscarNotas(Convert.ToInt32(txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim()));
        if (oCliente == null)
            return;

        txt_NomeCliente.Text = oCliente.Nome;

        foreach (var item in oNota.NotaLista)
        {
            PreencherLista(lista);
        }
        Txt_CodigoCliente_TextChanged(txt_CodigoCliente, new EventArgs());


        MascaraCampoCodigo.RetornarMascara(txt_CodigoCliente, new EventArgs());
        MascaraCampoCodigo.RetornarMascara(txt_CodigoNota, new EventArgs());
    }

    public void PrepararLista()
    {
        lvlListagemNotas.Clear();
        lvlListagemNotas.View = View.Details;
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Nº da Nota", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Nº do Funcionário", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Nº de Controle", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Data da Emissão", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Status", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Valor Pago", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Desconto", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Data Pagamento", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
    }
    public void PreencherLista(List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var linha = new string[8];
            linha[0] = item.NotaID.ToString();
            linha[1] = item.FuncionarioID.ToString();
            linha[2] = item.NumeroNota;
            linha[3] = item.DataEmissao.ToString();
            linha[4] = item.Status.ToString();
            linha[5] = item.ValorPago.ToString();
            linha[6] = item.Desconto.ToString();
            linha[7] = item.DataPagamentoFinal.ToString();
            var itmx = new ListViewItem(linha);
            lvlListagemNotas.Items.Add(itmx);

            Funcoes.ListviewColor(lvlListagemNotas);
        }
    }
    private void Txt_CodigoCliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
        {
            PreencherLista(lista);
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            int ClienteID;
            bool success = Int32.TryParse(txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim(), out ClienteID);

            if (success)
            {
                var listResult = new List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota>(from p in lista where p.ClienteID == ClienteID select p);
                PreencherLista(listResult);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O texto digitado não é um número inteiro.");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Como fez o debug? Entrou no o método `BuscarNotas` e verificou se você não está suprimindo alguma excessão ou se a consulta está correta?

Comment: Sim, ele faz a busca de notas, porém não exibe no listview

Comment: Mas onde você está fazendo o bind?